# UnitaryMatrixQ function not returning true for a unitary matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, expression-test

So I know this matrix is unitary. It's a well proven fact in quantum mechanics and you can even check for yourself on pen and paper, Heres a quick proof:

Assume $H$ is hermitian (i.e. $H^\dagger=H$) Then Define $U=\exp(-iH)$.

We can see that $U^\dagger=\exp(iH^\dagger)=\exp(iH)$

And that $U^\dagger U=UU^\dagger=\exp(iH-iH)=\exp(0)=I$

Belive me? Okay, So here's my mathematica code:

```
H = {{Re[a], b},{Conjugate[b], Re[c]}};
HermitianMatrixQ[H]
U = MatrixExp[-I H];
UnitaryMatrixQ[U]
```

And the output is `True` for the first query and `False` for the second. What gives?

Looking further into this, I think there are some expressions mathematica is getting confused about. If I express the hermitian matrix slightly differently, then do the same thing, I get this very strange result:

```
H = {{Re[a], Re[b] + I Re[c]},{Re[b] - I Re[c], Re[d]}};
U = MatrixExp[-I H];
FullSimplify[U\[ConjugateTranspose].U]
UnitaryMatrixQ[U]
```

which has the output:

```
{{1,0},{0,1}}

False
```

Which is just a straight up contradiction!

--- follow up ---

If I try the second codeblock, with the representation of the hermitian matrix as it is in the first, then mathematica runs for a very long time (too long for my computer at least)

Comment: Interesting observations.  I never used these functions.  There's this (as far as I know unwritten) rule that `...Q` functions will always return either `True` or `False` but nothing else.  Think `Equal` vs `SameQ`.  `a==1` stays unevaluated but `SameQ` always evaluates.  It's also a reason why `Positive` is not `PositiveQ`: `Positive[x]` does evaluate until `x` gets a value.  In light of this I find it a little strange that `UnitaryMatrixQ` and `HermitianMatrixQ` have the `...Q` naming and behaviour. Is `{{a,b},{c,d}}` Hermitian?  Well, it depends on the value of `b` and `c`!

Comment: But the function just says `False.`  So maybe this should be interpreted as "Hermitian for any value of `a,b,c,d`"?  But that interpretation brings its own problems too: sometimes the system just won't be able to check and come to a *certain* conclusion, yet the function will always return either `True` or `False`.  So what is going on?  I think that what is really happening is that the function computes the required criterion (i.e. $U\dagger U=I$), but then leaves it to the `SameTest` setting to test that condition.  You can set this manually and the documentation gives an example where

Comment: it is `SameTest -> (FullSimplify[#1 - #2] == 0 &)`.  If the `SameTest` doesn't return an explicit `True`, it is automatically assumed to be `False` (as if `TrueQ` were applied to it, think `TrueQ[a==1]`).  At least that's my idea about what is happening.  Thinking about it like this explains the behaviour and makes some sense.  I'm not sure if these comments constitute an answer ... I'll leave them as comments for now.

Comment: Yeah sure, I could get that if It can't work it out, then it would just return false. But If it can work out that `FullSimplify[U\[ConjugateTranspose].U]=={{1,0},{0,1}}` Then you'd think it could work it out with the Query. Perhaps those bits of code need a little tlc...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**tl;dr** If these functions cannot decide, they will simply return `False`.  A `False` result means that the selected equality testing method wasn't able to prove equality, but it does not mean that it was able to prove inequality.  Interpret the result relative to the used `SameTest` option value.

---

I will try to explain what I think is happening, though some of these are guesses.

**First some background**

`...Q` functions *always* return either `True` or `False` in Mathematica.  I have not seen this explicitly documented, but it seems to be true.  Examples:

`Equal[a,b]` does not evaluate for undefined `a` and `b`. `SameQ[a,b]` will always give `True` or `False`.

`Positive[a]` does not evaluate until `a` gets a numerical value.  It does not evaluate if the system cannot prove that the value is truly positive.  It won't give `False` in these cases.  It is not a `...Q` function.

`PossibleZeroQ` is a `...Q` function and will always give a definitive yes or no answer.  But the naming does reflect that this answer may not be correct.

`TrueQ` is often used to force a definitive `True` or `False` answer when this is needed.  E.g. `TrueQ[a==b]` will return `False` when `a` and `b` have no values.

**HermitianMatrixQ and UnitaryMatrixQ**

Symbolic calculations can not always be done.  [In fact deciding whether an arbitrary expression is identically zero is an undecidable problem.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ReducingExpressionsToTheirStandardForm.html) Thus I was surprised to see that these two functions are of the `...Q` variety and always return a definitive yes/no answer.

The only way I can make sense of this is if I think about these functions in a different way.  They do not actually check if a matrix `A` is Hermitian.  That check might not be possible at all, and oftentimes the answer would have to be "I don't know".  Instead `HermitianMatrixQ` does this:

- Compute `A == ConjugateTranspose[A]`.
- Use the `SameTest` setting to test for the equality.
- If the test gives `True`, return that.  Otherwise return `False`, *even if the test fails to give a definitive answer* (like `TrueQ`).

The documentation does not make it clear that this is what these functions do, but it appears to me that this is what is happening in reality.

The documentation however does give examples of special `SameTest` settings, e.g. [here](http://wolfram.com/xid/0dc28br78gcj-kgbail):

```
 SameTest -> (FullSimplify[#1 - #2] == 0 &)
```

This setting will make your second example return `True`

```
H = {{Re[a], Re[b] + I Re[c]}, {Re[b] - I Re[c], Re[d]}};
U = MatrixExp[-I H];

UnitaryMatrixQ[U, SameTest -> (FullSimplify[#1 - #2] == 0 &)]
(* True *)
```

Without this explicit `SameTest` setting we get `False` because the default `SameTest` is just not smart enough to prove this equality (but at least it is much faster than `FullSimplify`!)

What is a bit frustrating about this is that the default `SameTest` is unknown (hidden behind `Automatic`).  My guess is that it depends on whether the matrices are symbolic/exact or inexact numerical.

While this answer may not be what you were hoping for, I think that this way of looking at these functions will clarify what is happening.

Comment: @Xavier Thank you for the comments, I did not know that.  Is it otherwise generally true what I said about Q functions?  Are you aware of other exceptions (which are not as trivial as IsomorphicGraphQ saying that multigraph isomorphisms is not yet implemented)?

Comment: Ah, you are right, I assumed that the default value of `SameTest` was `SameQ`, but this not the case for `HermitianMatrixQ`. It is written that the default value is `Automatic` as you said. I may have seen this default value for another function using `SameTest`. I will try to find again which one it was.

Comment: @Xavier In practice `Automatic` means that it could be anything.  It could be as simple as `SameQ` or `Equal` or it could be a custom function not available to us users.  This is pretty common (and pretty annoying) with Mathematica.  One example is the `ComplexityFunction` option of `Simplify`.  People have been asking about this so much that they finally included it in the documentation. But `Automatic` generally means: unknown unless explicitly documented. My guess is that it's not a single function but selected based on the type of matrices.  It is likely different for numeric and symbolic.

Comment: @Xavier While sometimes annoying, these `Automatic` settings are understandable.  They want to provide a reasonable default for users, depending on the input.  I just implemented a `Method` option for a shortest path function in [IGraph/M](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM) today.  The default is `Automatic` and the method it chooses depends on whether the graph is weighted or not, whether there are any negative weights, and the size of the graph. Overall it tries to choose the fastest way that is likely to work well.

Comment: Yes, I agree about `Automatic`. I assumed that all `SameTest` were set by default to `SameQ` (rather than `Automatic` was always `SameQ` for `SameTest`), I guess I never paid close attention to the "Details and Options" section of the respective Qfunctions reference pages. Anyhow, this confusion is removed now, which is good. Also, thanks for the link to your package, I just downloaded it, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe `UnitaryMatrixQ` uses `PossibleZeroQ` under the hood? This returns false: `UnitaryMatrixQ[U, SameTest -> (PossibleZeroQ[#1 - #2] &)]`.

Comment: And we can debug further to see `FullSimplify` gives zero when `PossibleZeroQ` gives `False`. So maybe OP's input is just a case of `PossibleZeroQ` not giving `True`? `H = {{Re[a], Re[b] + I Re[c]}, {Re[b] - I Re[c], Re[d]}};
U = MatrixExp[-I H];
UnitaryMatrixQ[U, 
 SameTest -> (PossibleZeroQ[
     Echo[#1 - #2, "", {FullSimplify[#], PossibleZeroQ[#], #} &]] &)]`